# Plone - running bootstrap.py to start a fresh project fails: "The directory to be used as a download cache doesn't exist."

Tags: plone, zope, bootstrapper, buildout

I took the following steps:

**First** - Created a directory called `pln41` and a virtualenv called `pln41`. (I installed PIL in the virtualenv.)

**Second** - Entered the directory and ran:

```
wget http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/buildouts/plone-coredev/branches/4.1/bootstrap.py
```

**Third** - created the following `buildout.cfg` file:

```
[buildout]
extends = http://dist.plone.org/release/4.1/versions.cfg
parts = instance 

[instance] 
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
user = admin:admin
eggs = Plone
```

**Fourth** - ran `python bootstrap.py --distribute

The program produced the following output and crashed:

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.30.tar.gz
Extracting in /var/folders/xk/5xt9s5vd4bqd731qdkmxkxyr0000gn/T/tmpLrULV3
Now working in /var/folders/xk/5xt9s5vd4bqd731qdkmxkxyr0000gn/T/tmpLrULV3/distribute-0.6.30
Building a Distribute egg in /var/folders/xk/5xt9s5vd4bqd731qdkmxkxyr0000gn/T/tmp54ZJQK
/var/folders/xk/5xt9s5vd4bqd731qdkmxkxyr0000gn/T/tmp54ZJQK/distribute-0.6.30-py2.7.egg
While:
  Initializing.
Error: The directory:
'/Users/Jon/dev/pln41/~/.buildout/extends'
to be used as a download cache doesn't exist.
```

Now, I do have a directory called `.builtout/` in my home directory.  The problem is that placing the `~` sign in the middle of the path, like bootstrap is trying to do, is creating a problem.  If I try to run `cd /Users/Jon/dev/pln41/~/.buildout/` from anywhere, I get a "No such file or directory", but if I run `cd ~/.buildout/` then everything works fine.  Why is bootstrap creating this path: **/Users/Jon/dev/pln41/~/.buildout/extends**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is in your `~/.buildout/default.cfg` file? I would expect this:

```
[buildout]
eggs-directory = /Users/Jon/.buildout/eggs
download-cache = /Users/Jon/.buildout/downloads
extends-cache  = /Users/Jon/.buildout/extends
```

Make sure that you've created the directories that these lines reference.

Comment: The contents of my `~/.buildout/default.cfg` file are close to what you predict, but I user the `~` symbol instead of the full path.  I have:  `[buildout]
eggs-directory = ~/.buildout/eggs
download-cache = ~/.buildout/downloads
extends-cache = ~/.buildout/extends`

Comment: Okay, changing to fully qualified paths in my `default.cfg` file solved the problem for me.  Thanks.